# Access violation when assigning a value to my component Bitmap property

Tags: delphi, properties, bitmap, components

I'm trying to create a component that must use a Bitmap, I'm having a problem when I go to select the image on the property.

Here is an excerpt of the code:
Property Declaration

```
Property StarOff: TBitmap read FStarOff write SetStarOff;
```

Function SetStarOff

```
procedure TNotas.SetStarOff(const Value: TBitmap);
begin
FStarOff.Assign(Value);
end;
```

But, when I assign a value to the property, I get the error:

> Access violation at address 1BC324B8 in module 'TNte.bpl'. Read of address 000000000

Why is this happening?

Comment: All you have told us is "you are having a problem". At the moment you have told a story, but not asked a question. Give details, enough code for us to repro, and include the error message.

Comment: Desculpe, estou recebendo uma mensagem de erro ao tentar definir uma propriedade que eu estou tentando criar, que esta propriedade é um TBitmap. O erro aparece quando eu vou selecionar a imagem

Access violation at address 1BC324B8 in module 'TNte.bpl'. Read of address 000000000

Comment: Jose, SHOW THE ERROR MESSAGE. Do you want people to guess it?

Comment: Read of address 00000000 means that you are de-referencing a nil pointer. Perhaps you didn't assign anything to `FStarOff`. But we have to guess because you didn't give any information in the question.

Comment: @Ken Why did you delete your answer? It looks highly likely that it is accurate.

Comment: I#d guess you are using FStarOff without checking if it's assigned allready

Comment: Access violation at address 1BC324B8 in module 'TNte.bpl'. Read of address 000000000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your setter method looks correct, but you're getting an Access Violation because your FStarOff member is nil at the moment.

The usual is to create it at construction time and free it at destruction time.

```
constructor TMyComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FStarOff := TBitmap.Create;
end;

destructor TMyComponent.Destroy;
begin
  FStarOff.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it that was giving error!!!

Comment: And don't forget to assign an `OnChange` event handler to the `TBitmap` so you can react to changes to it, such as from `FStarOff.Assign()`.